# How to get non-standard php settings?

Tags: php, apache

I've got an old server set up by someone else who has long been gone and I now need to migrate the website running on it to a new server. So I want to include all the php settings which he set (apparently he changed a lot). To do this I would like to get a list of all the settings which he changed to a non-standard setting.

Is there a way to get all settings from the php.ini file which are different from the default settings?

Comment: Do a diff of the custom ini vs the default ini

Comment: This is a great tool, I've used it in the past to do the same: https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use vimdiff command if you are using vim:

```
vimdiff old.ini new.ini
```

There is Atom package which can do pretty good job for you:

https://atom.io/packages/split-diff

If you are using Sublime, there is side-by-side comparison tool for Sublime Text 2 and 3

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compare%20Side-By-Side

Or online ini compare: http://inicompare.io (Check example page)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can change the new php.ini against the old php.ini so you dont have to check whats diffrent.